# PHP MCrypt decryption fails unless using AES-256

Tags: php, encryption, mcrypt

I have written a class to encrypt and decrypt strings, but I can't use any cipher except `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256`. The program always report that the message is corrupted. How can I fix it?

The ciphers I have tested which fails are `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128` `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_192` `MCRYPT_BLOWFISH` `MCRYPT_SERPENT` and `MCRYPT_TWOFISH`.

Here's my code:

```
class Crypt {
    private $masterKey;
    private $subKey;
    private $cipher = MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 ;
    private $cipherMode = MCRYPT_MODE_CFB;
    //private $hashAlog = 'sha256';

    public function __construct($masterKey) {
        $this->masterKey = $masterKey;
    }

    public function setKey($masterKey) {
        $this->__construct($masterKey);
    }

    public function encrypt($message) {
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($this->getIVSize());
        $hmac = $this->signMsg($message);
        $this->genSubKey($iv);
        $cipherText = mcrypt_encrypt($this->cipher, $this->subKey, $message, $this->cipherMode, $iv);
        $cipherText = $iv . $hmac . $cipherText;
        return base64_encode($cipherText);
    }

    public function decrypt($enc_message) {
        $mixedMsg = base64_decode($enc_message);
        $iv = substr($mixedMsg, 0, $this->getIVSize());
        $this->genSubKey($iv);
        $hmac = substr($mixedMsg, $this->getIVSize(), strlen($this->signMsg(null)));
        $cipherText = substr($mixedMsg, $this->getIVSize() + strlen($this->signMsg(null)));
        $message = mcrypt_decrypt($this->cipher, $this->subKey, $cipherText, $this->cipherMode, $iv);
        if(!$message)
            die("Decrypt Error!");
        if($hmac != $this->signMsg($message))
            die("Message Corrupted");
        return $message;
    }

    private function genSubKey($iv) {
        $this->subKey = hash_pbkdf2("sha256", $this->masterKey, $iv, 50000, $this->getKeySize());
    }

    private function getKeySize() {
        return mcrypt_get_key_size($this->cipher, $this->cipherMode);
    }

    private function getIVSize() {
        return mcrypt_get_iv_size($this->cipher, $this->cipherMode);
    }

    private function signMsg($message) {
        return hash_hmac("sha512", $message, $this->masterKey, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: But I have limited the length to the key size, is that really needed?

Comment: No, you haven't limited the length of the `$subKey`. It's twice as long, because `hash_pbkdf2()` outputs hex-encoded bytes by default. You need to set raw_output to true.

Comment: Ok problem solved, I will update it as the answer.

Comment: I have no idea why `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256` would work and the others don't, but I have to say that `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256` is not AES-256. The 256 in AES means the key size, but the 256 for Rijndael means block size. AES is only defined for a fixed block size of 128 bit.

Comment: Oh I see, I have mixed them up. I also have no idea why this happen.

Comment: @2awm366 Don't feel bad, [mcrypt just sucks](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/if-you-re-typing-word-mcrypt-into-your-code-you-re-doing-it-wrong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the `hash_pbkdf2` function in the `genSubKey` function. Since `hash_pbkdf2` will output hex encoded strings, it will be twice as long as the key size. To solve this, we need to pass `true` as an additional parameter to it, let it output raw bytes and fit the key size.

Here's the corrected code:

```
private function genSubKey($iv) {
    $this->subKey = hash_pbkdf2("sha256", $this->masterKey, $iv, 50000, $this->getKeySize(), true);
}
```